# How to take information from a filename, and divide it up into several parts to save in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames, glob, h5py

I need to take this section of code and turn it into a function that will grab information from the filenames of the .h5 files in a directory. I am very new to python so hopefully my explanations here make sense. Below is the code, and under it, an example of the data filenames that it needs to parse.

```
atl06_dir = 'ATL06 files'
filenames = glob.glob(atl06_dir + '/*h5')
year_selected = 2019
filenames_selected = list()
for filename in filenames:
   product, year, month, day, hour, minute, second, track, cycle, granule, release, version = icesat2_data_utils.h5FilenameParts(os.path.basename(filename)) 
#need to replace this line with a function that grabs from the filename. This one does not work
   if int(year) == year_selected: 
      filenames_selected.append(filename)
```

How can I get this section to read the filename of .h5 files and output different sections of the name based on the seperations in name you can see in an example filename here:

ATL06_[yyyymmdd][hhmmss]*[ttttccss]*[vvv_rr].h5

I feel like I could be on the right track by asking it to read certain characters of the name such as this:

```
# product ATL06 = 0 to 5
# year yyyy = indexes 8 to 12
# month mm = 12 to 14
# day dd = 14 to 16
# hour hh = 18 to 20
# minute mm = 20 to 22
# second ss = 22 to 24
# Reference ground track tttt = 27 to 31
# cycle cc = 31 to 33
# orbital segment ss = 33 to 35
# version vvv = 38 to 44
```

Comment: Note that `glob.glob()` creates a list of filenames. You can avoid this with the iterator version: `glob.iglob()`. Your modified `for` loop would look like this `for filename in glob.iglob(atl06_dir + '/*h5')`

Answer (score 0):

You can either slice it according to your requirements, example,

```
string ="ATL06_[yyyymmdd][hhmmss][ttttccss][vvv_rr].h5"
product = string[0:5]
```

To extract things in `[]`, you can use the `regex` module :

```
import re
string ="ATL06_[yyyymmdd][hhmmss][ttttccss][vvv_rr].h5"
re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',string)
```

This returns a list of matching strings, :

```
['yyyymmdd', 'hhmmss', 'ttttccss', 'vvv_rr']
```

And each element in this string is a list, this can be sliced individually if required